# Downloading Matlab Support Package Raspberry Pi

Tags: matlab, connection, raspberry-pi, simulink, raspbian

I'm trying do download the MATLAB Raspberry Pi Support Package, but can't finish it due to an error occuring every time.
I can go through every step until I put the sd card back to my Raspberry Pi and use an ethernet cable to connect the Pi with my PC. Whenever Matlab tries to detect my Raspberry Pi, it throws an error message: "attempt to reference field of non-structure array."
What does this mean?

Information about my PC:
Windows 7, i7 processor, 64 bit, 8 GB RAM
MATLAB R2014a

Raspberry Pi:
OS: Raspbian
Version: Raspberry Pi B+
SD card HC = 16 GB

I watched videos in Youtube and did the same steps as everyone else, so I don't know where the problem is in my case. It would be nice, to hear some advice.

Greetings...

Comment: Can you state what steps you are following and the URL please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9V4Xcxlc9Q&list=FL9rtuYdzDO89Sv7za4KcCTA

Comment: Open Matlab R2014a-> Add Ons -> Get Hardware Support Packages -> Rasperry Pi (Simulink). After that, it downloads the Rasperry Pi Simulink Packages. After finishing the download I did the following steps: Board: Raspberry Pi B+ -> configure Network (manually with other ip-adress)->writing on sd card->removing sd card and putting it back to the board. Afterwars I used an ethernet cable and connected my Raspberry Pi with my PC. Then I continued in Matlab and tried to connect to the board, but this part didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to a bug in hardware detection step.
You can try R2018a with new hardware setup screens.