# Set up MATLAB and Simulink support package for Raspberry Pi

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi

I want to install MATLAB and Simulink support package for Raspberry Pi. I follow this [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/how-to-use-matlab-and-simulink-with-raspberry-pi/set-up-matlab-and-simulink-support-package-for-raspberry-pi) to do . I directly connect my laptop with Raspberry Pi using Ethernat cable.
But i didn't get output.

while installing i got error - "Could not detect a Raspberry Pi board on "Local Area Connection". Check your Ethernet connection to Raspberry Pi.
The FDX/LNK/100 LEDs on the Raspberry Pi board should be illuminated.
For network trouble-shooting instructions see http://www.mathworks.com">The MathWorks Web Site"

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: This is probably something you should ask MathWorks.  I don't know anyone here (that I know of) that has tried to connect to the Raspberry Pi with MATLAB.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753883/downloading-matlab-support-package-raspberry-pi

Comment: Is a proper IP assigned to your raspberry and your pc to allow a local communication? To simplify these steps I would connect both to the router and use DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced your same issue but after proceeding in this way I solved it.

Before you put the SD card on the Raspberry Pi you need:

1. power off the Pi
2. connect the Ethernet cable to the host computer
3. finally power on the Pi

In addition you may take a look at this [troubleshooting guide](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/5422/Raspberry%20Pi%20Firmware%20Upgrade%20Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps.

```
1. Open cmd and execute 'ipconfig'
   check for a network interface with '169.x.x.x' ip address

   If there is one, you could access your Pi via IP 169.254.0.2

   If there is none, check if your Ethernet port is enabled and no static IP is configured.
```

The above steps make sure that your Ethernet port is in proper state.
Repeat the hardware setup with direct connection in the network settings.